# Installing phpMyAdmin onto Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I've configured my EC2 instance as a LAMP, following [Amazon's tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html). That appears to be functioning correctly (I can see `phpinfo()` in a file I've uploaded OK).

I then tried to install phpMyAdmin by doing the following:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin
```

I can see that phpMyAdmin is now in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`, so I added an symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

I then edited `http.conf` to add `AllowOverride all` to `<Directory "/var/www/html">`. (Command: `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`)

And then restarted the server:

`sudo service httpd restart`

But whenever I visit `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/phpmyadmin` I get a 403 Forbidden response from the server: *You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.*

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to update the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` to allow remote users.

I just replaced the contents of the first `<directory>` tag like so...

I removed:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

 <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  # Apache 2.4
  <RequireAny>
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Require ip ::1
  </RequireAny>
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  # Apache 2.2
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
 </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And replaced it with this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And restarted the server: `sudo service httpd restart`

Works now!

Comment: its so weird i have two phpmyadmin `phpMyAdmin.conf` and `phpmyadmin.conf`

Comment: it's work but after set elastic ip it's not work page showing You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

Comment: This is kinda bad for security though. You do not want everyone to have access to your phpMyAdmin (by default).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and Chuck Le Butt's solution was very helpful, although a little different for me...

My ISP uses dynamic IP addresses so when I setup the server it was via a different IP. 
When I returned to it the following day, my IP address had changed so I was forbidden.
Butt, rather than allowing access from all IP's as Chuck suggested, I've updated my previous IP addresses in the phpMyAdmin.conf file.

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I replace

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.4
    <RequireAny>
      Require ip 127.0.0.1
      Require ip ::1
    </RequireAny>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.2
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
  </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAll>
       Require all granted
     </RequireAll>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from All
</Directory>
```

And it works~