# You don't have permission to access `phpmyadmin` on this server on amazon linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, lamp

I am trying to install phpmyadmin on amazon linux instance. I am trying for many days I am not an expert. I just followed step by step bellow document using putty

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

but my browser showing "You don't have permission to access `phpmyadmin`" I want to give access any/all ip for this server. Experts, Please help me I need a guideline.. Thanks a lot for Advanced.

Comment: What happened when you tried to search for this issue?

Comment: Hi AlBlue! Thanks a lot for your kind response. I got so many discussion and also got little confused as I said I am not an expert! I just found the bellow solution hope that might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324837/installing-phpmyadmin-onto-amazon-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0):

plan : 
1 yum install httpd mariadb mariadb-server php phpmyadmin -y

2 systemctl enable httpd mariadb

3 systemctl start httpd mariadb

4 open /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf and change all 127.0.0.1 with your workstation IP

5 open /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php and change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE; to FALSE

6 systemctl restart httpd

Then access http://vps/phpMyAdmin log in with root and no password